# ECL - Merging folders and files in the same parent folder

Tags: 2013-sp1, ecl

When I try to add folders and files in the same folder, all the elements that I'm adding are showed as folders.

My DisplayTypes:

```
    public IList<IDisplayType> DisplayTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IDisplayType>
            {
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bccf", "Countries", EclItemTypes.Folder),
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bctf", "Cities", EclItemTypes.Folder),
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bchf", "Hotels", EclItemTypes.Folder),
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bcci", "BrandCenter Country Image", EclItemTypes.File),
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bcti", "BrandCenter City Image", EclItemTypes.File),
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bchi", "BrandCenter Hotel Image", EclItemTypes.File)
            };
        }
    }
```

My MountPoint/GetFolderContent:

```
    public IFolderContent GetFolderContent(IEclUri parentFolderUri, int pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes)
    {
        var items = new List<IContentLibraryListItem>();
        var itemsImg = new List<IContentLibraryMultimediaItem>();
        if (parentFolderUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.MountPoint && itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.Folder))
        {
            requestCountries req = new requestCountries();
            req.initial = 0;
            req.number = 100;
            CountriesList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientCountriesList.getCountries(req);
            foreach(Country country in cs.countries){
                FolderBC f = new FolderBC(country);
                BrandCenterFolder h = new BrandCenterFolder(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, f);
                items.Add(h);
            }
        }

        if (parentFolderUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.Folder)// && itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.File))
        {
            if (parentFolderUri.SubType == "bccf")
            {
                requestCities req = new requestCities();
                req.paiId = int.Parse(parentFolderUri.ItemId);
                req.initial = 0;
                req.number = 100; 
                CitiesList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientCitiesList.getCities(req);
                foreach(City city in cs.cities){
                    FolderBC f = new FolderBC(city);
                    BrandCenterFolder h = new BrandCenterFolder(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, f);
                    items.Add(h);
                }

                requestImageCountries req2 = new requestImageCountries();
                req2.initial = 0;
                req2.number = 100;
                req2.paiId = int.Parse(parentFolderUri.ItemId);
                ImageCountriesList cs2 = BrandCenterProvider.ClientImagesCountries.getImageCountries(req2);
                foreach (ImageCountry c in cs2.countries)
                {
                    ImageBC i = new ImageBC(c);
                    BrandCenterImage image = new BrandCenterImage(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, i);
                    itemsImg.Add(image);

                    foreach (Indra.Tridion.ECL.BrandCenter.BrandCenter.Service.Client.CountryImages.Version v in c.versions)
                    {
                        ImageBC iv = new ImageBC(v, c.name, c.creation_date);
                        BrandCenterImage imageVersion = new BrandCenterImage(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, i);
                        itemsImg.Add(imageVersion);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (parentFolderUri.SubType == "bctf")
            {
                requestHotels req = new requestHotels();
                req.initial = 0;
                req.number = 100;
                req.ciuId = int.Parse(parentFolderUri.ItemId);
                HotelsList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientHotelsList.getHotels(req);
                foreach (Hotel c in cs.hotels)
                {
                    FolderBC f = new FolderBC(c);
                    BrandCenterFolder h = new BrandCenterFolder(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, f);
                    items.Add(h);
                }

                requestImageCities req2 = new requestImageCities();
                req2.initial = 0;
                req2.number = 100;
                req2.ciuId = int.Parse(parentFolderUri.ItemId);
                ImageCitiesList cs2 = BrandCenterProvider.ClientImagesCities.getImageCities(req2);
                foreach (ImageCity c in cs2.cities)
                {
                    ImageBC i = new ImageBC(c);
                    BrandCenterImage image = new BrandCenterImage(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, i);
                    itemsImg.Add(image);
                    BrandCenterProvider.hotels.Add(image.Id.ToString(), image);

                    foreach (Indra.Tridion.ECL.BrandCenter.BrandCenter.Service.Client.CityImages.Version v in c.versions)
                    {
                        ImageBC iv = new ImageBC(v, c.name, c.creation_date);
                        BrandCenterImage imageVersion = new BrandCenterImage(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, i);
                        itemsImg.Add(imageVersion);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (parentFolderUri.SubType == "bchf")
            {

                requestImageHotels req = new requestImageHotels();
                req.initial = 0;
                req.number = 10;
                req.hotId = int.Parse(parentFolderUri.ItemId);
                ImageHotelsList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientImagesHotels.getImageHotels(req);
                foreach (ImageHot c in cs.hotels)
                {
                    ImageBC i = new ImageBC(c);
                    BrandCenterImage image = new BrandCenterImage(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, i);
                    itemsImg.Add(image);

                    foreach (Indra.Tridion.ECL.BrandCenter.BrandCenter.Service.Client.HotelImages.Version v in c.versions) {
                        ImageBC iv = new ImageBC(v, c.name, c.creation_date);
                        BrandCenterImage imageVersion = new BrandCenterImage(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, i);
                        itemsImg.Add(imageVersion);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        items.AddRange(itemsImg);
        return BrandCenterProvider.HostServices.CreateFolderContent(parentFolderUri, items,
            false, CanSearch(parentFolderUri.PublicationId));
    }
```

Summarizing, When the GetFolderContent method starts is creating two lists:

```
    var items = new List<IContentLibraryListItem>();
    var itemsImg = new List<IContentLibraryMultimediaItem>();
```

During the process I add files or folders in every list.

When the method finish I merge both lists:

```
    items.AddRange(itemsImg);
    return BrandCenterProvider.HostServices.CreateFolderContent(parentFolderUri, items,
        false, CanSearch(parentFolderUri.PublicationId));
```

Then, In the GUI, is showing all the items as folders.

Definition of BrandCenterFolder:

```
public class BrandCenterFolder : ListItem, IContentLibraryItem
{
    public BrandCenterFolder(int publicationId, FolderBC info)
        : base(publicationId, info)
    {
        // if info needs to be fully loaded, do so here
    } ....
```

Definition of BrandCenterImage:

```
class BrandCenterImage : ListItem, IContentLibraryMultimediaItem
{
    public BrandCenterImage(int publicationId, ImageBC i)
        : base(publicationId, i) {}

    public IContentLibraryItem Save(bool readback)
    {
        return readback ? this : null;
    }  ....
```

My ListItem Class:

public class ListItem : IContentLibraryListItem
    {
       internal readonly FolderBC InfoFolder;
       internal readonly ImageBC InfoImage;

```
    private readonly IEclUri _id;

    public ListItem() { 
    }

    public ListItem(int publicationId, FolderBC info)
    {
        InfoFolder = info;
            _id = BrandCenterProvider.HostServices.CreateEclUri(publicationId, BrandCenterProvider.MountPointId, InfoFolder.id, DisplayTypeId, EclItemTypes.Folder);
    }

    public ListItem(int publicationId, ImageBC info)
    {
        InfoImage = info;
        _id = BrandCenterProvider.HostServices.CreateEclUri(publicationId, BrandCenterProvider.MountPointId, InfoImage.id, DisplayTypeId, EclItemTypes.File);
    }
```

Why is not showing the BrandCenterImage objects as files?

In the execution of the GetContentFolder method, when I arrive to the last folder of the tree, GetContentFolder is returning only BrandCenterImages. In this case, It's working fine and is showing this elements as files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the files show up in the tree view on the left, it is because you are ignoring the itemTypes parameter in GetFolderContent.

Only return files if `itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.File))` is true. And similarly, only return folders if `itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.Folder))` is true. If they are both true, return both folders and files.